# Given two angles, compute their smallest angular distance

Tags: geometry

We measure two angles over the time:

$a_1\in[0°,360°)$ and then $a_2\in[0°,360°)$

Can you think of a short way to compute their angular distance (the shorter one)?

So, if $a_1 = 5°$ and $a_2 = 355°$ their distance would be $10°$.

So far i've found the following correct formula. But I'd like to have a simpler formula:

$
\min \{
|a_1 - a_2|, \ |(a_1 + 360) - a_2|, \ |a_1 -(a_2 + 360)|\}
$

Maybe there might be a simpler formula with modular arithmetic, but I can't find a better solution. It would also be nice to have a sing (e.g., +1 for left, -1 for right, or vice-versa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be:

$180°-||a_1 - a_2|-180°|$

However, if there's a more elegant solution which even provides a sign I'm willing to accept it.